# django - login not submitting to server from dropdown

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to setup a dropdown login for my index.html page like so -

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top"></a></li>
          <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#howitworks">How it works</a></li>
          <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#api">API</a></li>
          <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="/dashboard/">Dashboard</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Login <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
              <form action='/login/' method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
                {% if form.errors %}
                    {{ form.errors}}
                {% endif %}
                <label for="id_email">Login:</label>
                <input type="text" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" name="email" id="id_email">
                <br />
                <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" name="password" id="id_password">
                <br />
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" />
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ current_path }}" />
              </form>
           </div>
           </li>
         {% endif %}
     </ul>
```

The problem is entering a username/password and hitting "Sign In" it's not actually doing anything.  The browser is asking me if I want to save the password locally but it doesn't seem to be sending any sort of request back to the server.

This is my urls.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', 'LoginRequest'),
    url(r'^data', include('companydemo.urls', namespace='client_access')),
    url(r'^dashboard', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="dashboard/index.html")),
    url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
)
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        email = forms.CharField(label=(u'Email'), max_length=30)
        password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Pass'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), max_length=30)
```

And this is my views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from forms import LoginForm

def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
            else:
                return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have the action URL and besides you are not using the form on your HTML. Try adding the action URL and using the form :D

Comment: I put the action="/login/" in as the urls.py is referencing my view.  I'm going to update the info I just did a major cleanup so I hope it makes more sense :)

Comment: The urls are wrong, Instead of 'LoginRequest' try removing the quotes and importing LoginRequest from your views.

Comment: that's helped I have a problem which seems to be from porting the code from PHP to python.  It's failing currently because it's looking for this `
[20/Jun/2015 23:30:18] "POST /mail/contact_me.php HTTP/1.1" 403 2295
`  I just have to figure out where/why it's doing this.  lol.

Comment: If you need help, here we are :)

Comment: That did it!  I removed the php code and it worked!  So the problem is the legacy bootstrap I'm using is using php for the contact me part which I need to convert to either pure javascript or python.  In the meantime the code is removed and the login is actually working :)